# nginx post method does not work

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-405

I have a problem with nginx to download an excel file using the Http POST method. In fact I am getting a Status Code: 405 Not Allowed.

here is my configuration

```
upstream backend{
    server localhost:9090;
    server localhost:9091;
    server localhost:9092;
    server localhost:9093;
}

server {
    listen       8887;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://backend;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_404; 
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

how can I solve this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you think this is an `nginx` problem? The configuration just passes the POST to the backend. It's most likely the backend that is issuing the 405 response,

Comment: In fact it's very bizzare, it sends me sometimes 404 sometimes 405.

Answer (score 7):

Nginx responds with an HTTP 405 for POST requests that try to access a static asset.

From the Nginx release docs from a few years back:

`*) Feature: now Nginx returns the 405 status code for POST method
       requesting a static file only if the file exists.`

A way to go around it would be to add this line, which changes the response code and sends you to the requested URI:

`error_page 405 =200 $uri;`

You can find other solutions here:

http://invalidlogic.com/2011/04/12/serving-static-content-via-post-from-nginx/

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I changed the architecture of my app to have only one port.

Comment: This bit me when I didn't return a response from a FastAPI POST endpoint and FastAPI converted that to a JSONResponse (the string `null`), which nginx counted as static. Thanks.